# LLVM cannot find clang binary

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I have just built and installed LLVM Clang 3.5.0 with compiler-rt. *clang* binary seems to work, but cannot build a simple test program:

```
$ cat hello.c 
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Building it borks with `error: unable to execute command: Executable "" doesn't exist!`

```
$ clang hello.c -o hello
error: unable to execute command: Executable "" doesn't exist!
```

Executable "" ?  Interesting...

Debugging it further reveals that clang tries to call itself to build `.o` object file and then ld to link it, but does not know where itself exists apparently.

```
$ clang -### hello.c -o hello
clang version 3.5.0 (tags/RELEASE_350/final)
Target: x86_64-alpine-linux-musl
Thread model: posix
 "" "-cc1" "-triple" "x86_64-alpine-linux-musl" "-emit-obj" "-mrelax-all" "-disable-free" "-main-file-name" "hello.c" "-mrelocation-model" "static" "-mdisable-fp-elim" "-fmath-errno" "-masm-verbose" "-mconstructor-aliases" "-munwind-tables" "-fuse-init-array" "-target-cpu" "x86-64" "-target-linker-version" "2.24" "-dwarf-column-info" "-resource-dir" "../lib/clang/3.5.0" "-internal-isystem" "/usr/local/include" "-internal-isystem" "../lib/clang/3.5.0/include" "-internal-externc-isystem" "/include" "-internal-externc-isystem" "/usr/include" "-fdebug-compilation-dir" "/" "-ferror-limit" "19" "-fmessage-length" "158" "-mstackrealign" "-fobjc-runtime=gcc" "-fdiagnostics-show-option" "-o" "/tmp/hello-37746e.o" "-x" "c" "hello.c"
 "/usr/bin/ld" "-z" "relro" "--eh-frame-hdr" "-m" "elf_x86_64" "-dynamic-linker" "/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1" "-o" "hello" "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/4.8.3/../../../crt1.o" "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/4.8.3/../../../crti.o" "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/4.8.3/crtbegin.o" "-L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/4.8.3" "-L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/lib" "-L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/4.8.3/../../.." "-L/../lib" "-L/lib" "-L/usr/lib" "/tmp/hello-37746e.o" "-lgcc" "--as-needed" "-lgcc_s" "--no-as-needed" "-lc" "-lgcc" "--as-needed" "-lgcc_s" "--no-as-needed" "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/4.8.3/crtend.o" "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/4.8.3/../../../crtn.o"
```

When I run the first line putting `/usr/bin/clang` as the first item, it builds just fine:

```
$ /usr/bin/clang "-cc1" "-triple" "x86_64-alpine-linux-musl" "-emit-obj" "-mrelax-all" "-disable-free" "-main-file-name" "hello.c" "-mrelocation-model" "static" "-mdisable-fp-elim" "-fmath-errno" "-masm-verbose" "-mconstructor-aliases" "-munwind-tables" "-target-cpu" "x86-64" "-target-linker-version" "2.24" "-dwarf-column-info" "-resource-dir" "../lib/clang/3.5.0" "-internal-isystem" "/usr/local/include" "-internal-isystem" "../lib/clang/3.5.0/include" "-internal-externc-isystem" "/include" "-internal-externc-isystem" "/usr/include" "-fdebug-compilation-dir" "/" "-ferror-limit" "19" "-fmessage-length" "158" "-mstackrealign" "-fobjc-runtime=gcc" "-fdiagnostics-show-option" "-o" "/tmp/hello-4f64bb.o" "-x" "c" "hello.c"
$
```

And following `/usr/bin/ld` is able to link it just fine resulting in:

```
$ ./hello
Hello World
```

Anny suggestions what did I screw during configure/build?

Comment: So how did you acquire this build of clang? What operating system are you on? What does `which clang` result with?

Comment: I have built it myself. I am on _Alpine Linux 3.1_. ```which clang``` reports ```/usr/bin/clang```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clang source analysis shows that 'clang' program on Linux uses `/proc/self/exe` to find out real path of its binary. I am running in  chroot without /proc mounted, thus it failed.

```
mount -t proc proc /proc
```

solves the issue